# keyboard accessible dropdown hover menu

Tags: php, css, wordpress, tabs, accessibility

So I am using the `pytheas` theme for a website, and it needs to be fully accessible.  I have completed all other requirements other than navigating the dropdown menu items using the keyboard, or specifically the `tab` key.  It goes through all the headings of the menu, but does not go down into the `dropdown` elements.

I was thinking of linking each menu heading to open up to a dropdown `instead of a new page`, but how would I do that?  The only way currently that I can even see the dropdown elements is when i `hover` my mouse over the heading

Is there a way to do this? Or is there an even easier way to make the menu accessible?

Here is a link to a [sample page in pytheas theme](http://wpexplorer-demos.com/pytheas/).

Answer (score 1):

This menu is now keyboard accessible. This link has good info on making menus keyboard accessible (needs JS) and adapted for screen readers that interpret ARIA attributes - http://simplyaccessible.com/examples/css-menu/option-6/

```
.nav-menu > li > a:focus, 
.nav-menu > .current-menu-item > a:focus, 
.navigation .current-menu-parent > a:focus, 
.navigation .current-menu-parent > a:focus, 
.nav-menu > .current-menu-item > a:focus, 
.nav-menu ul a:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F15A23;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-menu li:focus ul, 
 ul.show-menu   {
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**See it implement here in the WP menu:
Use TAB key and arrows (for example down arrow to get to features level 2.)**

http://fiddle.jshell.net/L9y5U/9/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/L9y5U/9/show/

Comment: woo! this looks great so far! thank you for helping. only problem left is that when i press the down arrow after i go on a header menu tab and the dropdown opens, it does not tab to any of the dropdown items, i can only see them but still not navigate

Comment: also, for the example you linked, is there a way to look at the code of it? or do i have to get all the css files from inspect element?

Comment: it is all in the jsfiddle - CSS is the one from your example in external resources, extra CSS in CSS panel of fiddle and JS is JS panel. You do can navigate to the dropdown menu using up down arrow and the dropdown menu items you use up and down arrows or tab. You can also use left and right arrows to navigate.To launch the page press enter.

Comment: You may need to alter the script a little to enable the enter key to go to a link. e.keyCode == 13

Comment: hm... would the browser i am using be of any importance? in chrome, i am looking at this link http://fiddle.jshell.net/3RN9H/4/show/ as well as my localhost but the up/down arrows do not allow me to navigate between the submenu links

Comment: also, there are no extra javascript in jsfiddle, or is that the part i am missing? :o

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/L9y5U/9/ See the updated answer above. (refresh this page maybe)

Comment: thank you, i see the js and it is working perfectly. i just have one more embarrassing questions (as i should know how to do this), and that is how can i add the js file to my wordpress child theme? 

i have tried making it a js file and put it in the js folder in child theme, then called on it using "function header-js()" in functions.php but it seems to not work and make my whole site blank... 

tl;dr how do i add js to my theme?

Comment: No idea. Maybe this helps http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-include-javascript-and-css-in-your-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-24321

Comment: i have added js to my site, cheers! one more question though- i noticed that in your jsfiddle you set the framework to jquery1,7,2 and  made it onDomReady- these things i do not know how to set in my website and thus it does not create the same effect as in your jsfiddle. do you prehaps know how i can change these settings?

Comment: In the fiddle JS panel this is a short notation for document ready $(function(){
 // INVOKE YOUR SCRIPTS
});
Maybe this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-update-jquery-javascript-library

Comment: i have been trying $(function{} out but i couldn't get it to go to domready state, if you know anything else can you please explain a little further?